# Edit attachment in web client

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

Document with attachments is opened in XPage. I want to edit attachment in associated program (say MS Word or Excel) and save changes back to Notes document.

I am aware of webdav configuration, but it have significant caveats: attachments are no longer stored within related document and security is controlled by ACL and not RN/AN.

How to edit document attachments in web client? Did any of you implemented such feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebDAV is the way to go. There's an implementation that can read/write DominonAttachments. Soon on OpenNTF

Comment: can I help, at least with ideas and use cases?

Comment: Accepted, project deployed http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=WebDAV%20for%20IBM%20Domino and works great! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Given that it would have to be opened in another program such as word / excel I'm not sure if this is possible, for example if your looking to save edits then you would need to know when someone saves the doc in word /excel etc.

You can attach a file download control to a domino doc field, when you do this it will display all attachments, when in edit mode you can delete these attachments, I think the only way this would work would be to enable them to delete / re upload, which is a fairly common thing to do on most web applications I would think

Comment: To delete and reupload file might be common practice for web applications. I see it as big downgrade for our users, though. From UX point of view it is unacceptable option.

Comment: the only other option i could see would be to have a web version of every piece of software that could be used for these files (word, excel, powerpoint etc.) and try find a way to tap into a save event and post it back to your xpages app or the domino server. I wouldn't think this is an XPages limitation more on the lines of web applications not having the ability to access the users file system and access their applications

Comment: there are more options, I think. for example, dedicated webdav container for temporary editing. or servlet responsible for upload/download of attachments with logic to find and replace recent version of attachment. my question is about finding possibilities...

Comment: Quickr is supposed to have a "round-trip editing" component which allows you to edit attachments from a web-client inplace. They use ActiveX for it.

Answer (score 0):

The tool we use, with recent improvements for XPages, is Swing: http://www.swingsoftware.com/

We checked many others, without success.